# Upgrading Hibernate to 6.1 - How to specify the equivalent of @Type(type="text")?

Tags: java, hibernate

We're currently using Hibernate 5.6 but are trying to upgrade to Hibernate 6.1. In one entity we have this property:

```java
@Type(type = "text")
private String someText;
```

But in Hibernate 6.1, the `type` field in the `@Type` annotation is removed. Now the `@Type` annotation is defined like this:

```java
@java.lang.annotation.Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Type {

    /**
     * The implementation class which implements {@link UserType}.
     */
    Class<? extends UserType<?>> value();

    /**
     * Parameters to be injected into the custom type after it is
     * instantiated. The {@link UserType} implementation must implement
     * {@link org.hibernate.usertype.ParameterizedType} to receive the
     * parameters.
     */
    Parameter[] parameters() default {};
}
```

Question: What's the equivalent of `@Type(type = "text")` in Hibernate 6.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [Hibernate 5.0 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic) - For `text` BasicTypeRegistry key corresponds `LONGVARCHAR` Jdbc type.

And in [Hibernate 6.1.5 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-String) is offered the option to use `@JdbcTypeCode` annotation:

```
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.LONGVARCHAR)
private String text;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Georgii Lvov is a great one. I would just like to add that there's an alternative:

```
@JdbcType(LongVarcharJdbcType.class)
```

is almost synonymous with `@JdbcTypeCode(Types.LONGVARCHAR)`. Which one you use is, I guess, a bit of a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the proper syntax for using `@Type` with Hibernate 6+, but as a workaround, you may try using the `@Column` annotation:

```java
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String someText;
```